# How to find out the relationship between variables?

Tags: regression

I have two variables *Distance* and *Slope*. These go into a model resulting in a *cost* variable. I like to figure out the influence of the variables Distance and Slope on the Cost variable. I have several hundred test numbers for the variables. What programs or steps could I use to see the impact of the two variables on the cost?
In the end I would like to know for example *Distance* influences the *Cost* variable too 70 %. *Slope* influence *Cost* too 30 %.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This sounds like you want a multiple regression model.  However the topic is much more than can be covered in a forum like this.  To do a proper regression model (and be sure that it is the correct model) really requires at least 2 courses in statistics (more recommended).

So, you should either enroll in some statistics courses (or find the equivalent self-study) or consult with a local statistician who can make sure that you are doing the right thing and help you understand the results.

Comment: Thanks Greg for your answer. Now I know at least that it is more complicated than I thought. I will talk to a statistician at my company.